# Unable to display MVC 5 validation error messages on view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a specific problem using MVC 5 validation to display error messages if the user hasn't properly entered everything on the page. The HTML markup of the form is as following:

```
                @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterDo", "User", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = "First name", @class = "form-control", @type = "text" })



                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { placeholder = "Last name", @class = "form-control", @type = "text" })


                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Email", @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordConfirm, new { placeholder = "Confirm password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })


                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCountryId)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCountryId, Model.Countries, "-- Please select a country --", new { @class = "select2_single form-control select2-hidden-accessible", @tabindex = "-1" })

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input class="btn btn-default submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
                    </div>
                }
```

Please note that I have a dropdown list that I need to fill initially when the view is rendered (i.e. I have to pass the countries list onto the view in order to render it properly). The issue that I have here is that when I click the "register" button, the code from my action isn't triggered AT ALL. Instead I simply get the URL in my browser as following:

```
http://localhost:60617/user/register?FirstName=&LastName=&Email=&Password=&PasswordConfirm=&SelectedCountryId=
```

And the error messages are not displayed at all... The code isn't triggered at all...

These are my two actions:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Register")]

        public ActionResult DoRegister(UserRegistrationViewModel model)

        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new Users();
                user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                user.LastName = model.LastName;
                user.Email = model.Email;
                user.PasswordSalt = Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreateSalt(40);
                user.PasswordHash = Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, user.PasswordSalt);
                user.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(model.SelectedCountryId);
                user.Active = true;
                Connection.ctx.Users.Add(user);
                Connection.ctx.SaveChanges();
                var role = new UserRoles();
                role.RoleId = 2;
                role.UserId = user.UserId;
                role.Active = true;
                user.UserRoles.Add(role);
                Connection.ctx.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Register", model);
            }
        }
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            var model = new UserRegistrationViewModel();
            var countries = Connection.ctx.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName).ToList();
            model.Countries = new SelectList(countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
            return View(model);
        }
```

First action is responsible for rendering the view, and second one is responsible for logic when the user registers...

What am I doing wrong here. I'm missing out something very obvious here, but I just cant see it... :(

Edit here is the ViewModel:

```
  public class UserRegistrationViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required!")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required!")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email name is required!")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password name is required!")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password confirmation name is required!")]
        public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country needs to be selected!")]
        public int SelectedCountryId { get; set; }


        public SelectList Countries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: At first, you don't need to change `post` method name and can you show your Model?

Comment: Where is the Model??... Show the Validations your are putting on the properties.

Comment: @SeM I included the model

Comment: @ShashankSood I edited my first post , can you look into it?

Comment: Did you make your post method name `RegisterDo` for reason? and also you need to pass your model back to view `return View("Register", model);`

Comment: Hi @SeM Yes I made it separately to process the logic of the registration. The "Register" action is there just to render the view :)

Comment: @User987 If you create your post method with same name, and call your method by the name, if there is `[HttpPost]` attribute, that method will not be called.

Comment: are you sure you are adding your jquery and jquery unobtrusive validation in you scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[ActionName("Register")]` attribute to your post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Register")]
public ActionResult RegisterDo(UserRegistrationViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new Users();
        user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        user.LastName = model.LastName;
        user.Email = model.Email;
        user.PasswordSalt = Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreateSalt(40);
        user.PasswordHash = Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, user.PasswordSalt);
        user.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(model.SelectedCountryId);
        user.Active = true;
        Connection.ctx.Users.Add(user);
        Connection.ctx.SaveChanges();
        var role = new UserRoles();
        role.RoleId = 2;
        role.UserId = user.UserId;
        role.Active = true;
        user.UserRoles.Add(role);
        Connection.ctx.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: should I change anything in the "Html.Beginform(...)" part?

Comment: No I think..... if its not triggered, delete the inner part of `Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: But how am I gonna then know which action is gonna be triggered if I just leave Html.BeginForm()? :D

Comment: @User987 ok, listen, if you just leave `Html.BeginForm()` then if you submit your view, it will pass to controller and will search the ActionMethod with `[HttpPost]` attribute and same name, from where your view came.

Comment: @User987 you can see examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/6380/crud-operation#t=201610281100424262646)

Comment: I did as you told me ,  I left just Html.BeginForm().. And now when I click the submit button it calls the Register action which is rendering the view... Not the one responsible for message displaying.. lol this is some dark magic involved

Comment: @User987 so just make your post method with same name. But anyway I didn't told you do empty that part, I said 'No I think..... if its not triggered, THEN delete the inner part...'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126906/discussion-between-user987-and-sem).

Answer (score 1):

```
else
{
    var countries = Connection.ctx.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName).ToList();
    ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
    return View("Register", model);
}
```

pass a model again to your view

Comment: Okay  I did that, but the issue is that my action "RegisterDo" isn't being triggered at all... :/

Comment: Do you pass UserRegistrationViewModel as a model in your view

Comment: @model UserRegistrationViewModel, as I see that you didn't pass it in Register GET

Comment: Either change the name of action in View to "RegisterDo"
or
Add 
    [ActionName("Register")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterDo(UserRegistrationViewModel model)

Comment: How would that look like, can you edit your response so that I can see? Or ? What's the other solution ? :D

Comment: public ActionResult Register()
{
    // your code

    return View(new userResistrationViewModel());
}

and in your view 
@model userResistrationViewModel

Comment: @User987 try to use `[Route("Register")]` or change name of your Action to be Register as GET .. this is the standard

Comment: Now my register action for rendering view is being called , not the one responsible for handling the logic when user registers :(

Comment: @User987 not understand .. which function being called now ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is just fine except the else part which should be

```
return View("Register", model);
```

Passing the model is required to view those error messages.
And to Hit action method
Either change the name of action in View to "RegisterDo"

or

Add

```
 [ActionName("Register")] 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterDo(UserRegistrationViewModel model)
```

Comment: You have a point yes, I passed the model back into the view.. But? the code for the RegisterDo action isn't being triggered at all... :/

Comment: Make your View POST method look like:
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post))
if you are adding ActionName("register") attribute above the action method